# How to delete a Single Gmail contact using PHP

Tags: php, google-contacts-api

I'm using this script try to delete contacts from GMAIL but it couldn't delete.

I am refer: https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts/delete

**My Script:**

```
$id = '******'; 
$contact_mail = '********';
$contact_id = '************';

$contactXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry gd:etag="*">
<id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/'.$contact_mail.'/base/'.$contact_id.'</id>
<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/'.$contact_mail.'/full/'.$contact_id.'"/>
<link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/'.$contact_mail.'/full/'.$contact_id.'"/></entry>'; 

    $headers = array(
    'Host: www.google.com',
    'Gdata-version: 3.0',
    'Content-length: '.strlen($contactXML),
    'Content-type: application/atom+xml',
    'Authorization: OAuth '.$access_token
    );

    $contactQuery = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/'.$contact_id.'';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $contactQuery );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contactXML);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);           
    print_r($result);
```

Please find where I am wrong or guide me any other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your OAuth header is incorrect. Change `Authorization: OAuth ...` to `Authorization: Bearer ...`
2. Delete requests do not take content.
3. The documentation you link to and the API you are calling are totally different. You linked to a Glass API but you are invoking the Contacts API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3

There are several other things that could be wrong (particularly with how the OAuth token was fetched) but without the actual error message you are receiving from the server it is impossible to definitively diagnose.